# How to calculate total online time using laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-7

I want to calculate particular user's total online time for selected date. Below is MySQL table -
[User Active Status Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYLFa.png)

In status column I store values as 0 (Offline) and 1 (Online).
As you see user_id 33 is online at -

1. 10:05:25
2. 14:00:00

and offline at -

1. 11:45:58
2. 19:00:04

So, How to calculate total online time using Laravel?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and post your data as text or fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can try to refactor a bit your database..
Add 3 columns `date, logged_in_time, logged_out_time` and you can make an event listener each time user logs in our out. Any time they will log in our out it will be stored in your table and you can filter easily by dates in your query.
If you want to calculate the amount of time they were logged in for a specific date you will just do 'logged_out_time - logged_in_time'